# How to avoid closing MongoDB connection, and keep Node app flowing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The issue I have is that I write a lot of data (approx 16,000 entries) where each entry is uploaded to my Mongo database, because I iterate through these in a `for` loop it was not possible to open and close a connection upon every iteration - it would crash my application.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydatabase");
    //run sql query to get data
    for(result in sqldata) {

    myobj = {Number: sqldata[result].Num} //<--- this for loop produces 16000 entries

    dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document inserted");
      db.close(); //<--- this is the issue
});
}
```

});

If I use `db.close()` it crashes my app as I do not bring the connection back inside the loop.

If I move `db.close()` outside of the loop it uploads all of the documents but doesn't continue working through the rest of the script - it just stalls.

This has been frustrating me for quite some time as I am new to JS, any help is greatly appreciated

thanks.

Comment: You're not supposed to open and close the MongoClient connection pool. Just connect on start up and leave it open.

Comment: Why not use [`insertMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)?  Is there a specific reason you are using `insertOne`?  You can do an asynchronous loop, but it would be better to just upload all at once.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for the response, but why is `db.close()` necessary? If it's not there it will get stuck in a loop

Comment: If this is a utility program rather than a web service, then you'd want to call `db.close()` after your async `insertMany` or bulk insert operations have completed.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks, how exactly does `insertMany` work? Could I build an object which contains all 16k + objects and insert each one individually to the MongoDB?